# Sabre Dev API Car Rental Price

Tags: api, sabre

I am testing out Sabre Dev Car Rental API and I'm confused about the price
in the response.

With the following parameters:

```
"NumDays": "8",
"NumHours": "2",
"PickUpDateTime": "12-21T09:00",
"ReturnDateTime": "12-29T11:00"
```

There are 4 different prices as shown below:

VehicleCharge=>Amount: $405.00

VehicleCharge=>AdditionalDayHour=>Day=>Rate: $57.86

VehicleCharge=>AdditionalDayHour=>Hour=>Rate: $19.29

VehicleCharge=>TotalCharge=>Amount: $727.89

Which one is the daily price and which one is the total price?

[image: Sabre Dev API Price]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea these price breakdowns can be a bit odd.  At least you mostly have it standarised through the GDS.  If you go direct like we use to do, you will get prices from Hertz one way and Dollar another and so and so....

Anyway your price breakdown is as follows:

VehicleCharge=>Amount: $405.00 **Base rate for the vehicle,  No tax add ons, airport fees, etc. **

VehicleCharge=>AdditionalDayHour=>Day=>Rate: $57.86 ** Amount that will be charged if you keep past the drop off time (Hence the additional Day tag) **

VehicleCharge=>AdditionalDayHour=>Hour=>Rate: $19.29 ** Cost per hour if you keep the vehicle past drop off time (Hence the Additional Day Hour tag)**

VehicleCharge=>TotalCharge=>Amount: $727.89 ** Actual cost of the vehicle for the allotted time including taxes, fees, etc. **

Hope this helps clear things up.